# (GCC) Dollar sign in printf format string

Tags: c, gcc, format, printf

I've seen the following line in a source code written in C:

```
printf("%2$d %1$d", a, b);
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's an [extension to the language added by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) (C11-compliant behaviour should be as described in an answer by @chux). Notation `%2$d` means the same as `%d` (output signed integer), except it formats the parameter with given 1-based number (in your case it's a second parameter, `b`).

So, when you run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 2;
    printf("%2$d %1$d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

you'll get `2 3` in standard output.

More info can be found on [printf man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

Answer (score 15):

Per the C spec C11dr 7.21.6.1

As part of a print format, the first `%` in `"%2$d %1$d"` introduces a directive.  This directive may have various flags, width, precision, length modifier and finally a conversion specifier.  In this case `2` is a width.  The next character `$` is neither a precision, length modifier nor conversion specifier.  Thus since the conversion specification is invalid,

**... the behavior is undefined.**  C11dr 7.21.6.1 9

The C spec discusses future library directions.  Lower case letters may be added in the future and other characters may be used in extensions.  Of course `$` is not a lower case letter, so that is good for the future.  It certainly fits the "other character" role as `$` is not even part of the C character set.

In various *nix implementations, `$` is used as describe in [Linux Programmer's Manual  PRINTF(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).  The `$`, along with the preceding integer defines the argument index of the  width.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt  Does this get close enough to the whole story?

Comment: sure, exactly what is to be said concerning the standard