# Passing too few arguments to printf for the format specifier — is it undefined behavior?

Tags: c, printf, posix

As I know, having too few format specifiers for the arguments is considered as undefined behavior (and having too few arguments for the format specifiers is also undefined behaviour). Does this apply to:

```
printf("%1$d %1$d", 5);
```

**PS** Use of `"%1$d"` as format specifier is [an extension to the `printf` family of functions added by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: A format specifier.

Comment: Those are format specifiers. So yes. Why wouldn't it apply? @SouravGhosh It's a POSIX thing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19327441/2757035

Comment: but that's a non-iso-C format specifier, so since this is a bit of a language-lawyer question, we might want to specify *which* version of C we're actually talking about

Comment: ...and if you're asking _because_ you're using extended specifiers and wonder whether that affects the answer about whether this is UB, then say so in the question. Context is key. Having a plausible reason for asking will reduce negative response to the question. That said, I'm pretty sure this will be equally UB, because why - or physically how - would POSIX go out of its way to make it well-formed?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  can you explain more your comment in an answer stating the view of every version ?

Comment: no, I don't know the laws of the hundreds of different C implementations out there.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `1$` is roughly equivalent to using `*`, except that you can specify exactly which argument contains the runtime field width or precision.  So both `"%1$d %1$d"` are reading the field width from the first argument (5).  The behavior is still undefined because two arguments are still missing.

Comment: @rondino: as per P.P's answer, this might be legal according to one C standard, but illegal under another. Which document applies is pretty much a combinatorical, philosophical and mostly: a compiler implementation problem

Comment: You probably want to add POSIX tag because ISO C doesn't provide the format specifier we're talking about.

Comment: @P.P. fun fact, no matter which `--std=` I use, gcc warns about ISO incompatibility with `-Wall`

Comment: @P.P. oh, wait, that only happens because of `-Wpedantic` that I auto-insert in my GCC calls

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's right. `-Wpedantic` warns about extensions.

Comment: @P.P. I'm just a little surprised that `-std=c11` considers POSIX an extension...

Comment: @MarcusMüller To GCC when `-std=c11 -Wpedantic` is used, `POSIX` is an extension ;-)

Comment: @P.P. but to which `-std` spec is it *not* an extension, then?

Comment: @MarcusMüller `-std=` and `-Wpedantic` mostly catch them. GCC manual says "The particular standard is used by -Wpedantic to identify which features are GNU extensions given that version of the standard." But it sometimes warns not only about GNU extensions but others too (like here). Experimentally, I can see that GCC doesn't warn about any POSIX functionalities as long as `-pedantic` is *not* used. This is the same with `gnu11`, `c11` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `n$` notation is not part of standard C, but is part of POSIX. The POSIX specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) supports the `n$` notation to refer to arguments.

> Conversions can be applied to the nth argument after the format in the argument list, rather than to the next unused argument. In this case, the conversion specifier character `%` (see below) is replaced by the sequence `"%n$"`, where *n* is a decimal integer in the range [1,{NL_ARGMAX}], giving the position of the argument in the argument list. This feature provides for the definition of format strings that select arguments in an order appropriate to specific languages (see the EXAMPLES section).
>
> The format can contain either numbered argument conversion specifications (that is, `"%n$"` and `"*m$"`), or unnumbered argument conversion specifications (that is, `%` and `*`), but not both. The only exception to this is that `%%` can be mixed with the `"%n$"` form. The results of mixing numbered and unnumbered argument specifications in a format string are undefined. When numbered argument specifications are used, specifying the Nth argument requires that all the leading arguments, from the first to the (N-1)th, are specified in the format string.
>
> In format strings containing the `"%n$"` form of conversion specification, numbered arguments in the argument list can be referenced from the format string as many times as required.

It requires that you provide an argument for each `n$`, and that the format string refers to every argument 1..n.  It doesn't say you have to use a different `n$` each time.

The code shown is fine on POSIX systems.  Since it uses a POSIX-only feature, it won't be portable to non-POSIX systems that don't have the necessary support as an extension.

Comment: the conclusion the code is fine but not portable. right ?

Comment: It will be portable to POSIX-compliant systems.  It will not be portable to POSIX non-compliant systems, which isn't a surprise when you use a POSIX-specific feature.

Comment: One more thing please: `The results of mixing numbered and unnumbered argument specifications in a format string are undefined`  does it mean `%*d %nd` in  the same format string is undefined

Comment: More or less.  Using `printf("%d %2$d\n", 1, 2)` mixes the unnumbered and numbered notations and the result is undefined.  You get what you get.  And it doesn't matter whether the sequence is unnumbered-numbered or numbered-unnumbered — any mixture is undefined.  (`printf("%*2$s\n", "undefined", 7);` is undefined behaviour, for example.)

Answer (score 3):

This is valid in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), which says:

> In format strings containing the "%n$" form of conversion
>   specification, numbered arguments in the argument list **can be
>   referenced from the format string as many times as required.**

(emphasis mine)

There are constraints on the `%n$` format specifier but are not relevant to the question. See the linked POSIX manual for them.

But a [strict reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329488/1275169) of C standard appears to say this is *undefined*.

Comment: Note, however, that the reason that the behavior is undefined according to C is not that there are too few arguments, but rather "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined."  C designates the '%' character in a format string as beginning a conversion specification, but the conversion specifications so indicated in the OP's example are invalid as far as ISO C 2011 is concerned.

Comment: Indeed. The post I linked explains it quite neatly.