# printf an argument twice

Tags: c, printf

I want to pass one extra argument to `printf` and print it twice, e.g.

```
printf("%s%s","somestring");       // prints somestringsomestring
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327441/gcc-dollar-sign-in-printf-format-string

Comment: In ISO C you would need to use a variable (or a varargs list) to hold the value, and then specify it twice in the arguments list

Comment: Is there practical need for this or this is theoretical question?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are on Linux or some other UNIX like system, you can use `$` to specify the argument number:

```
printf("%1$s%1$s\n", "hello");
```

In this example, `1$` means "use the first argument".  We also use this syntax multiple times so we can use a given argument more that once.

The [Linux man page for `printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) gives more details:

> The arguments must correspond properly (after type promotion) with the
>   conversion specifier. By default, the arguments are used in the order
>   given, where each '*' and each conversion specifier asks for the next
>   argument (and it is an error if insufficiently many arguments are
>   given). One can also specify explicitly which argument is taken, at
>   each place where an argument is required, by writing "%m$" instead of
>   '%' and "*m$" instead of '*', where the decimal integer m denotes the
>   position in the argument list of the desired argument, indexed
>   starting from 1. Thus,
>
> ```
> printf("%*d", width, num);
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> printf("%2$*1$d", width, num);
> ```
>
> are equivalent. The second style allows repeated references to the
>   same argument. The C99 standard does not include the style using '$',
>   which comes from the Single UNIX Specification. If the style using '$'
>   is used, it must be used throughout for all conversions taking an
>   argument and all width and precision arguments, but it may be mixed
>   with "%%" formats which do not consume an argument. There may be no
>   gaps in the numbers of arguments specified using '$'; for example, if
>   arguments 1 and 3 are specified, argument 2 must also be specified
>   somewhere in the format string.

Comment: Thanks  very much. Will accept when the system lets me.

Comment: Just a note per `man 3 printf`: "*The C99 standard does not include the style using '$', which comes from the Single UNIX Specification.*"

Comment: ^ in other words, this is a POSIX extension

Comment: Also, is there any way I could do `printf("hello%s");` and have it print `hellohello%s`, e.g. print the 0th argument? `0$` is nonworking.

Comment: @0xBADC0DE No, that won't work.  The format string is what defines what the following arguments are.  It can't reference itself in that way.

Comment: any idea how to implement this on windows?

Comment: @MSallal use `_printf_p` on Windows