# Exploits in use of Externally-Controlled Format String

Tags: c

first, please look thought this website (https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/134.html). They are some code is having vulnerability. I not really understand where is the vulnerability code, them talking about.

It has 3 code snippets with vulnerability such as PrintWrapper, Snprintf and %1$d, present on this website.

Comment: Hi, you should review our questions quidelines on https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
 Everything you need is on that website you provided, and if you don't know what something does, simply google `[name of the language] [function you don't know]`. In this case `C sprintf`. %[stuff] is formating, it should be described on sprintf article.

Comment: bro maybe i ask question not that clear... actually u guys need go in the website and look thought it. what inside talking. this website limited word, so i can;t write a lot of thing in here. actually this topic is talking vulnerability of printWrapper, snprintf and %1$d.

Answer (score 1):

@CassieJade you need to look at the documentation of these functions online. 
`printf, snpritf` are pretty common functions. And by the way, this platform is not for school assignments. You are most welcome if you have tried something and want to follow from there.

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
2. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

The following explains beautifully about your concern of $.
[(GCC) Dollar sign in printf format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327441/gcc-dollar-sign-in-printf-format-string)

Notation `%2$d` means the same as `%d` (output signed integer), except it formats the parameter with given 1-based number (in your case it's a second parameter, b).

```
int a = 3, b = 2;

printf("%2$d %1$d", a, b);
```

Here you would expect 3 2 to be printed, but it will print 2 3, because the parameter a becomes param#1, and b becomes param#2, and %2$d is printed first so 2 is printed first followed by %1$d which is 3

You may want to look at [man page](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) of printf, its a bit complex for newbies but its the final source of truth.

The following is your print wrapper.

```
char buf[5012];
memcpy(buf, argv[1], 5012);
printWrapper(argv[1]);
return (0);
```

> Your website says: When an attacker can modify an
>   externally-controlled format string, this can lead to buffer
>   overflows, denial of service, or data representation problems.

Now, if this argv[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) can be provided by someone who is not trusted, he can provide any junk argument which will go to printf. The goal of your task is to not to feed on print() with any string that is externally controlled. 
e.g. argv[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) can be very huge string (max allowable).
Or for example I am the one invoking your program and I passed argv[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) as "%d Hello World", your printWrapper will end up printing some junk like "-446798072 Hello World", because no integer is passed as argument in printf(argv[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)).

Also memcpy is reading fixed number of bytes from origin argv[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) which can have shorter length string, in this case it will be an invalid read (read past bound).

> `snprintf(buf,128,argv[1]);`

exploit here is very clear, the argv[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) can be changed with containment of several specifiers like %n which can write n number of bytes to your buf rather than intended write. By using %X in argc[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) hacker can gain address of a variable on stack which can be exploited further. All this is vulnerable because an external untrusted source is creating the format specifier string that is used by your printf or snprintf, sprintf functions.
For example suppose hacker gave "%200d" in the argv[1](http://%20http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). `sprintf(buf, 128, argv[1]);`
will land up printing 200 bytes and then a junk integer, which might not be intended at all, since its snprintf which is a bounded function it will allow only 128 bytes to be written which will be empty.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: actually, now i doing a assignment is about how to prevent vulnerability. i give u the website, inside all the code that have vulnerability. i need to explain and prevent the code. i not just only need to know the function only. function i already research. but the prevent code is the problem only.

Comment: For example, this website give me this coding only printf("%d %d %1$d %1$d\n", 5, 9); it's say the output will be 5 9 5 5. but when i try the answer is 5 9 %d %d. Then i keep research at website but i found nothing. i found this %1$d is all related to android coding.

Comment: anyone can do one example of %1$d. how to use this code?

Comment: ohh thx so much. it help a lot. then how about the solution coding? It's better not using argv[1]?

Comment: Now since you understand the issue, and its an assignment, try and think on your own.