# I want to the same string multiple times in C via printf

Tags: c, printf, declaration, cs50, string-literals

I'm doing Harvard CS50, and in the second class on C, the instructor says %s would automatically print each extra argument in succession.

Okay, that's cool. But what if I want to print the first string multiple times?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   char firstname[5] = "Bruce";
   char lastname[5] = "Wayne";

   printf("Hi, %s!\nI am your virtual butler. I will call you Master %s from now on.\nWelcome to %s Manor!", firstname, lastname);
}
```

However, It outputs:

```
Hi, BruceWayne!
I am your virtual butler. I will call you Master Wayne from now on.
Welcome to  q��U Manor!
```

Instead of:

```
Hi, Bruce!
I am your virtual butler. I will call you Master Wayne from now on.
Welcome to Wayne Manor!
```

I've tried searching on Google and did not find relevant information to fix the issue myself.

---

Update #1:

As per suggestions, I made changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   char firstname[] = "Bruce";
   char lastname[] = "Wayne";

   printf("Hi, %s!\nI am your virtual butler. I will call you Master %s from now on.\nWelcome to %s Manor!", firstname, lastname);
}
```

It outputs:

```
Hi, Bruce!
I am your virtual butler. I will call you Master Wayne from now on.
Welcome to  ���(V Manor!
```

It's still having trouble with Wayne Manor.

---

Update #2

```
printf("Hi, %s!\nI am your virtual butler. I will call you Master %s from now on.\nWelcome to %s Manor!", firstname, lastname, lastname);
```

Works as intended!

Comment: `char firstname[5] = "Bruce";` Too short. "Bruce" requires 6 characters. Remember the null terminator.

Comment: C strings ALSO require the terminating `'\0'`... Don't count letters; let the compiler do it correctly: `char firstname[] = "Bruce";` (Less maintenance when "Bruce" is changed to "George"...) The compiler knows best...

Comment: Those are not C strings, but character arrays, which cannot be passed to functions expecting a C string.

Comment: You need a parameter to match each format specifier. If you want a value to be used for more than one format specifier, provide it more than once.

Comment: If you can use POSIX extensions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327441/gcc-dollar-sign-in-printf-format-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that these arrays

```
char firstname[5] = "Bruce";
char lastname[5] = "Wayne";
```

do not contain strings. You need either to enlarge arrays to include the terminating zero character '\0' of the string literals like

```
char firstname[6] = "Bruce";
char lastname[6]  = "Wayne";
```

or to allow the compiler itself to calculate sizes of the arrays like

```
char firstname[] = "Bruce";
char lastname[]  = "Wayne";
```

Another problem is that the format string contains three conversion specifiers `s` but you supplied only two corresponding arguments

```
printf("Hi, %s\nI am your virtual butler. I will call you Master %s from now on.\nWelcome to %s Manor!", firstname, lastname);
```

You need to write adding one more argument

```
printf("Hi, %s\nI am your virtual butler. I will call you Master "
       "%s from now on.\nWelcome to %s Manor!", 
       firstname, lastname, lastname);
```